# Using .each to iterate in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to iterate through a table using the jquery .each function as such:

```
    $("#" + tableID).each(function () {
    if ($("#" + this).hasClass ('notSelected')) {
          selected ($("#" + this).attr ('id')); 
        }
    });
```

Basically I want to go through each row. Send the id of that row to a function called selected. I am getting a syntax error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: `this` contains a reference to the element, not its id. So you should replace `$("#" + this)` by `$(this)`. Then your code is iterating through all the tables, not rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, your code is attempting to loop through each element on the page that has an ID that matches the value of the `tableID` variable. Append the `tr` selector to your existing selector to loop through each row. Also, since you're using the `tr` selector, `$(this)` inside of the loop refers to the jQuery row object.

```
$("#" + tableID + " tr").each(function () { 
if ($(this).hasClass("notSelected")) { 
      selected($(this).attr("id"));  
    } 
});
```

Comment: That's it. Keep in mind that this will loop through ALL table rows, including header rows. You can avoid that by using "tr:gt(0)" if you know your header row is first, or better yet, add <thead></thead> and <tbody></tbody> tags and loop through "tbody tr" instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But just curious why my code wasn't working. Was it looking at the <td>'s instead of the <tr>'s?

Comment: Falcata: it was looking at all matched <table>s, actually.